# Separate letters - Image processing OCR

Tags: image-processing, ocr, matlab

```
I = imread('TEST_2.JPG');
Igray = rgb2gray(I);
Ibw = im2bw(Igray,graythresh(Igray));
Iedge = edge(uint8(Ibw));
se = strel('square',2);
Iedge2 = imdilate(Iedge, se);
Ifill= imfill(Iedge2,'holes');
imshow(Ifill)
```

Most of the numbers are separated and recognized but there are few numbers pretty close to each other and therefore it is recognized as one number. Is there any way to separate those mixed numbers?
Sorry, I am new here and not allowed to post pictures until 10 reputation.

Comment: Can you try calling  imerode before imdilate? Also post a link to the pic on imgur or something. A mod might come by and edit your post.

Comment: tried that... it returns all black image

Comment: Did you use imerode on Ibw instead of Iedge2? If you use erode on Iedge2 it will return all black.

Comment: dint work.. same result

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it to work. 
instead of writing OCR code in matlab, I used matlab for pre-processing image and refine it to max. and then use MS-OneNote to get the text from images.

So far everything looks good...

Thanks all for your help!!